# Is it possible to write an ASSERT_NEVER macro?

Tags: c++, macros, assert

I'd like to write a C++ macro `ASSERT_NEVER` that would raise a **compile-time** warning when control flow can possibly reach that point. Something like this:

```
class Base { protected: explicit Base(); };
class A: public Base {};
class B: public Base {};
// class C: public Base {};

void doSomething (Base *pObj)
{
    if (dynamic_cast<A*>(pObj) != NULL) doA();
    else if (dynamic_cast<B*>(pObj) != NULL) doB();
    else ASSERT_NEVER("You forgot one case, dude!");
}
```

So, the above code would compile with no warning. As soon as you put `class C` in, the compiler would stop and emit the warning.

Is it possible to write such a macro?

The idea arose, because TypeScript has such a concept. See [assert-never](https://www.npmjs.com/package/assert-never).

Comment: In C++, calling that function as `doSomething((Colour) 3)` is perfectly valid, so in your example, it *should* give a warning.

Comment: Oops, you're quite right...

Comment: In this specific instance GCC can warn if not all enumerations are in a switch statement, combined with C++11 enum class and you can cover _this_ case.

Comment: You mean like [static_assert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert)?

Comment: The example is bad, I'll rewrite it.

Comment: I've rewritten the example. I now use dynamic_casts rather than enums. The point is not the switch statement, it's the control flow.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: I believe that static_assert(false) will always fail. But I want it to fail when control flow can actually reach it.

Comment: Your example is still ungood. Nothing stops anybody deriving from `Base` in another translation unit, and calling your function. The only way to know here if a certain flow is reached, is to reach it.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. I guess it's not possible to write such a macro in any meaningful manner, then.

Comment: In addition to what @StoryTeller points out, there's nothing preventing `doSomething(new Base)` either.

Comment: I added a protected constructor to Base, so at least this is now impossible.

Comment: You can still derive from `Base` somewhere else and pass to the function. Regarding the question: you should rather use a static analyzer instead.  You can also try `-Wunreachable-code` or `-Werror=unreachable-code` to make it an error, though it won't catch all cases (clang only, it seems).